# Flask Error When I run program

Tags: python, flask

I have friend helping with English this time.

I have more problems with getting new route to loading.

I have this testing code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')


@app.route('/order')
def index():
    return render_template('order.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And I get this error:

```
 View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index
```

Please help me. I hope English better.

Comment: You appear to be defining `index` twice.

Comment: I've have two answers. Which one I make accept?

Comment: Totally up to you, but if you have no other basis, I'd go for the earliest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define `index()` two times. You have to change name one of the function.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a function `index` twice in the same scope. The flask decorator is making it sound more complicated than that, is all.